# Excel randomly opening files when I try to close a file

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a problem with Excel that occurs multiple times a day and is totally random. Whenever I have multiple excel workbooks opened and I try to close one by right clicking the icon on the taskbar and clicking "close window", instead of closing the file it will open a random saved excel workbook. The workbook then gets automatically pinned. It doesn't get pinned to my taskbar but when I right click an excel file it gets pinned above RECENT.

Has anyone have this issue before? I can't seem to find a solution and it is bugging me a lot since it happens frequently.

I am using excel 2010.

Edit - The file that opens is always the same file. Even if I unpin it and go about my day eventually it will happen again and it is the same file.

Comment: Can you check on the VBA editor if `Personal.xlsb` has any code? Likely a script there firing when files are closed or some specific situations.

Comment: I don't see my personal.xlsb, I might not have it? I went to the VBA editor press ctrl+g and entered ?Application.StartupPath. Went to the directory and there is no file there. Show hidden files is enable as well

Comment: Do you have any addins loaded in the application which are doing something special. Also, if you have a reference to a workbook (i.e. Tools References) this will cause the workbook to load.. or possibly something like that. I'd start off to see what is loaded in the background (addins COM addins etc) and then try to remove these types of things first to get a minimum Excel instance and see if the problem persists.